# Google Play IAP Test Subscription Purchase Cancels Itself?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I can successfully purchase a test subscription using flutter in_app_purchase library. The test purchase renews every 5 minutes, but after some time, say 30 minutes the subscription cancels itself. Is this normal for test subscriptions? I didn't see any documentation stating that test subs get cancelled after some time or after some number of renewals.

The response I receive from billing:

```
{acknowledgementState: 1, autoRenewing: false, cancelReason: 1, countryCode: US, developerPayload: , expiryTimeMillis: 1703700378086, kind: androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase, orderId: GPA.3354-2333-7678-79
557..5, priceAmountMicros: 2990000, priceCurrencyCode: USD, purchaseType: 0, startTimeMillis: 1703698295955}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's by design. That's what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#renewals) say:

> Test subscriptions renew more quickly than actual subscriptions, and test subscriptions can renew a maximum of six times.